# getJSON sending null parameter to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

Guys, Im calling a JsonResult but the "getJSON" is sending a null parameter to controller.

In JS I have this...

```
var ID = $("#Id").val();
$.getJSON("/Orders/JSON", ID, function (data) {
    ....    
};
```

The var ID has a valid value. I don't know where I'm going wrong.

```
public JsonResult JSONEnvolvidosPedido(string ped)
    {
         ...
    }
```

What am I missing?

Tks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are sending data to a server, it needs to be in `key=value` form.  You're just sending a value.

You should probably do something like this:

```
$.getJSON("/Orders/JSON", {id: ID}, function (data) {
    ....    
};
```

The exact name of the key (`id` here) depends on your server-side code's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

be sure to add JsonRequestBehavoir.AllowGet

```
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```